# Why does flex-basis calculation return an error in SASS?

Tags: css, sass

So I was quickly typing out a flex-grid generator in `scss` as I often do, but for some weird reason this returns an error now. From my assumption this is totally correct and should simply compile to the desired classes. I'm using a `12-col-grid` system, this is my approach `flex: 0 0 #{100 / 12 / $i}%;`, I propably miss something really obvious. [My Codepen.](https://codepen.io/MrFuze/pen/abdMMxR)

```css
@mixin colSpan {
  @for $i from 1 through 12 {
    .col-#{$i} {
      flex: 0 0 #{100 / 12 / $i}%;
      max-width: #{100 / 12 / $i}%;
    }
  }
}

@include colSpan;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the `%` to the `100`

```css
@mixin colSpan {
  @for $i from 1 through 12 {
    .col-#{$i} {
      flex: 0 0 #{100% / 12 / $i};
      max-width: #{100% / 12 / $i};
    }
  }
}

@include colSpan;
```